# Any way in ElasticSearch it would automatically increase the cluster size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

Is there any way in Amazon elastic search, that it automatically adds the data nodes when the used size of the cluster is about to reach the maximum? Or someone, always have to do it manually?

Comment: Are you using the AWS managed service, or self-hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. AWS doesn't provide that out of box but there are other means to handle this. Some of the many options available are mentioned here

https://www.haptik.ai/tech/auto-scaling-for-aws-elasticsearch/

Comment: The article linked above has moved to https://www.haptik.ai/tech/auto-scaling-for-aws-elasticsearch/ The "[s]uggested edit queue is full" so I can't edit the post to update the link.